# How to test a component that isn't exported in React

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, istanbul

I'm recently joining the react user base and using jest/enzyme for testing.

I have a class, whose render method looks something like:

```
render() {
  const Orange = ({ text }) => (<span className="orangeText" > {text}</span>);
  const headerText = flag ? (<Orange text="a"/>) : (<Orange text="b"/>)
  return (<div>{headerText}</div>)
}
```

Istanbul says that the line where Orange is defined is uncovered. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to cover it, and if my design should be different.

I'm testing the class with something like `wrapper.shallow(<MyClass/>)`
Thanks for any input.

Istanbul report:
[image: istanbul report]

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the Istanbul report pls ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would make more sense to me to define the component outside the render function instead of redefining it again on each render / state change:

```
const Orange = ({ text }) => (<span className="orangeText">{text}</span>)

export default class Whatever extends React.Component {
    …

    render() {
      return (<div><Orange text={flag ? "a" : "b"} /></div>)
    }
}
```

Btw. something like [`styled-components`](https://www.styled-components.com/) might be worth trying for such uses:

```
import { styled } from "styled-components"

const Orange = styled.span`
    color: orange;
    font-size: 1.1em;
`

export default class Whatever extends React.Component {
    …

    render() {
      return (<div><Orange>{flag ? "a" : "b"}</Orange></div>)
    }
}
```

Comment: I will mark this as the answer. I moved the constant declaration outside of my class, and added `export` in front of it. So in the testing file I can do `import { Orange } from "MyClass"`. I had tried this before, but forgot the brackets. So doing a `shallow(<Orange text="test"/>)` fixes the coverage issue just fine.

Comment: @MattWilde i think the coverage issue was because the definition (`const Orange = …`) was there again and again on every render, and it was used (= covered) only when the `Orange` component was actually rendered (`this.state.downstream` in your screenshot was true)

Comment: it still wasn't covered by simply moving the `const` out of the render block and above the class declaration. I had to import `Orange` into my test file and do a shallow render before it finally got cleared.

Comment: Ah :) Thanks for the details!